# inserting data into postgresql database with codeigniter

Tags: php, database, postgresql, codeigniter

i have a problem when i try to insert a row in my user table in postgresql, e.g.

I have the normal insert with active record, $this->db->insert($table,$data) and i get an error something like this:

ERROR: it does not exists the column Â«user_accountsÂ» in the relation Â«user_accountsÂ» LINE 1: INSERT INTO "user_accounts" (**"user_accounts"**."uacc_group_fk"

and i think the problem could be the table name inside the fields that i will insert (**"user_accounts"**."uacc_group_fk"),.

Do you know how can I avoid this? i just want to put the name of fields without table name.

Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: Foreign key relationship error?

Comment: what is your $data look like?

Comment: Banzilla- it is not a foreign key error, @Shaiful Islam- My variable $data is an array:                                      $data =array($this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['group_id'] => $group_id,
$this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['email'] => $email,
$this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['username'] => ($username) ? $username : '',
$this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['password'] => $hash_password,
$this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['ip_address'] => $ip_address,);

Comment: @DeutscheMexa Can you include the DDL for the table `user_accounts` in your question? This way we can think of a more relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the column "user_accounts"."uacc_group_fk" exists ( with quotes )?

this is the data array used in  insert_user fuction of https://github.com/haseydesign/flexi-auth/blob/master/library_files/application/models/flexi_auth_model.php:

```
$sql_insert = array(
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['group_id'] => $group_id,
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['email'] => $email,
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['username'] => ($username) ? $username : '',
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['password'] => $hash_password,
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['ip_address'] => $ip_address,
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['last_login_date'] => $this->database_date_time(),
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['date_added'] => $this->database_date_time(),
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['activation_token'] => $activation_token,
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['active'] => 0,       
        $this->auth->tbl_col_user_account['suspend'] => $suspend_account        
    );
```

Comment: Yes i have checked that before, and it gets all the values correctly but the problem is that postgresql take this table name as a column name so it can not recognize it.